# Picard rank of Jacobian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, jacobians

Let $C$ be a curve over field $k$, let $J$ be its Jacobian.

(1)Suppose $C$ has no nontrivial automorphism, $k$ is algebraically closed, is it true that $\mathrm{NS}(J)\cong\mathbb{Z}\cdot\theta$? Here $\theta$ is the theta divisor.

(2)Suppose $k$ is the function field of $\mathcal{M}_g$, where $\mathcal{M}_g$ is the moduli of genus $g>2$ curves over $\mathbb{C}$. Does $\mathrm{NS}(J)$ has rank $1$? (Is there a good reference for this?)

(3)Suppose $k$ is the function field of $\mathcal{M}_g$, where $\mathcal{M}_g$ is the moduli of genus $g>2$ curves over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. Does $\mathrm{NS}(J)$ has rank $1$?

Comment: If $C$ admits a nonconstant morphism to a curve of genus $>0$, then $\text{NS}(J)$ has rank $\geq 2$, even if $C$ has only the identity automorphism.  The Franchetta conjecture, proved by Harer, implies the result from (2), although it does take a little work to reduce (2) to the Franchetta conjecture.  The Franchetta conjecture was extended to positive characteristic by Stefan Schroeer.

Comment: But (2) and (3) are much easier than the Franchetta conjecture, I think -- it seems to me that it is enough to show that the action of $G_k$ on $H^2(J, Q_l(1))$ has $1$-dimensional space of invariants, which (a) can be reduced to characteristic zero, and (b) in characteristic zero follows as $H^2(J, Q_l(1))=\wedge^2 H^1(J, Q_l(1))$; and the image of $G_k$ in $GL(H^1(J, Q_l(1)))$ is dense in $Sp_{2g}$, by a complex-analytic calculation.  (Not that this is exactly an easy argument...)

Comment: @DanielLitt.  You are correct, that is a much simpler proof.  The analogous theorem for the moduli space of all principally polarized Abelian varieties (not only Jacobians) is a theorem of Arthur Mattuck.

Comment: I think a more elementary proof of (2) nd (3) can be obtained by applying the theory of Lefschetz pencils to a pencil of cuves of genus $g$ on a suitable surface, e.g. $P^1 \times P^1$.

Comment: @ulrich.  Yes, I believe that also works.  The full Franchetta conjecture can also be reduced to such a result for linear systems (the Enriques conjecture), but I believe there is still no proof of the Enriques conjecture that is independent of the proof of the Franchetta conjecture.